# Rearranging multiple cell contents in Excel/R with variable fields

Tags: r, excel, tidyverse

I'm having a bit of a data wrangling headache with this issue.
I have a table in Excel generated by copy-pasting from a website, in which each row represents a sample. Within this row there is a particular field that contains a variable number of cells. 
I attach a screenshot so that you can easily understand what I mean:

[image: excel screenshot 1]

Now, what I want to do is to have each of these fields in a separate column. Had this been a fixed number of rows, I would simply transpose by "Paste special", then break the resulting line at a fixed number of fields in order to have everything in a tidy fashion.
However, the number of fields per row changes; not all samples have the same number of attributes, and this means that transposing the whole column would not be enough. What I have been doing now for some minutes is transposing everything and manually moving cells so that there are blanks where there is no value, but the number of attributes stays the same for every row:

[image: excel screenshot 2]

However, this is tedious, time consuming and since I have more than 500 entries will take forever.

I am not at all fluent in excel scripting, but I have a semi-decent knowledge of wrangling in base R. The main issue I have to tackle is that if I import this table as a text file within R, every cell in that column will be assigned a row on its own, making the collapsing quite complex.

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
#This is the data I need to wrangle
tmp <- read.delim("pdata.txt", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
> head(tmp)
            Title             Source.name             Disease.state    Sex Age
1 LT000842RU_CTRL Flash frozen whole lung                   Control 1-Male  75
2                                                                           NA
3                                                                           NA
4                                                                           NA
5  LT001600RL_ILD Flash frozen whole lung Interstitial lung disease 1-Male  54
6                                                                           NA
  Gold.stage              Characteristics Ild.subtype Pneumocystis.colonization
1  0-At Risk       smoker?: 2-Ever (>100)
2            %predicted fev1 (pre-bd): 96
3             %predicted fvc (pre-bd): 97
4                     %predicted dlco: 78
5               %emphysema (f-950): 1.903   2-UIP/IPF
6                  smoker?: 2-Ever (>100)
```

As you can see there are empty spaces in the "Title" column, which are caused by the "Characteristics" column having more entries for the same title.

```
#Extremely ugly series of gsub to make for compatible colnames (no spaces, no dashes, etc)
d = sapply(tmp[,7], function(x) {gsub(x, pattern = " ", replacement = "_", fixed = T)})
dd = sapply(d, function(x) {gsub(x, pattern = "%", replacement = "", fixed = T)})
dd = sapply(dd, function(x) {gsub(x, pattern = "_(f-950):_", replacement = " ", fixed = T)})
dd = sapply(dd, function(x) {gsub(x, pattern = "?:", replacement = "", fixed = T)})
dd = sapply(dd, function(x) {gsub(x, pattern = "smoker_", replacement = "smoker ", fixed = T)})
dd = sapply(dd, function(x) {gsub(x, pattern = ":_", replacement = " ", fixed = T)})
dd = sapply(dd, function(x) {gsub(x, pattern = "(", replacement = "", fixed = T)})
dd = sapply(dd, function(x) {gsub(x, pattern = ")", replacement = "", fixed = T)})
dd = sapply(dd, function(x) {gsub(x, pattern = "-", replacement = "_", fixed = T)})


  #Use the character vector that has been gsubbed as the attributes column in the df
tmp[,7] = dd


#Take the rows that are not empty, i.e. those that have the name of the sample and will be the starting rows for the attributes
    nonempty = which(tmp[,1] != "")
    jumps = nonempty[2:length(nonempty)]-nonempty[1:length(nonempty)-1]
    jumps = c(jumps, 0)

#Make dummy columns with the same names as the gsubbed attributes
tmp$emphysema = tmp[,1]
tmp$smoker = tmp[,1]
tmp$predicted_fcv_pre_bd = tmp[,1]
tmp$predicted_fev1_pre_bd = tmp[,1]
tmp$predicted_fev1_post_bd = tmp[,1]
tmp$predicted_fcv_post_bd = tmp[,1]
tmp$predicted_dlco = tmp[,1]

#This is a loop to fill in the columns with the values extracted from the gsubbed attributes column
for(i in 1:length(nonempty))
{
    a = as.data.frame(tmp[seq(nonempty[i], (nonempty[i]+jumps[i]-1),by = 1),7])
    chars = colnames(tmp[,10:ncol(tmp)])
    for (j in chars)
    {
        gg = as.character(a[grep(pattern = j, x = a[,1]),1])
        if(length(gg) != 0) tmp[nonempty[i],j] = as.character(unlist(strsplit(gg, split = " "))[2]) else tmp[nonempty[i],j] = NA
    }
}
# Make the new df by only taking the rows with samples
tmp2 = tmp[nonempty,]

#This is the resulting data frame:
> head(tmp2)
                          Title             Source.name
LT000216LL_ILD   LT000216LL_ILD Flash frozen whole lung
LT000379LU_ILD   LT000379LU_ILD Flash frozen whole lung
LT000842RU_CTRL LT000842RU_CTRL Flash frozen whole lung
LT001600RL_ILD   LT001600RL_ILD Flash frozen whole lung
LT001796RU_CTRL LT001796RU_CTRL Flash frozen whole lung
LT002410RM_ILD   LT002410RM_ILD Flash frozen whole lung
                            Disease.state      Sex Age Gold.stage
LT000216LL_ILD  Interstitial lung disease 2-Female  70
LT000379LU_ILD  Interstitial lung disease   1-Male  63
LT000842RU_CTRL                   Control   1-Male  75  0-At Risk
LT001600RL_ILD  Interstitial lung disease   1-Male  54
LT001796RU_CTRL                   Control   1-Male  48  0-At Risk
LT002410RM_ILD  Interstitial lung disease   1-Male  52
                   Characteristics                       Ild.subtype
LT000216LL_ILD     emphysema 0.051                         2-UIP/IPF
LT000379LU_ILD  smoker 2_Ever_>100 9-Hypersensitive Pneumonitis (HP)
LT000842RU_CTRL smoker 2_Ever_>100
LT001600RL_ILD     emphysema 1.903                         2-UIP/IPF
LT001796RU_CTRL smoker 2_Ever_>100
LT002410RM_ILD      emphysema 0.03                         2-UIP/IPF
                Pneumocystis.colonization emphysema      smoker
LT000216LL_ILD                                0.051     3_Never
LT000379LU_ILD                                 <NA> 2_Ever_>100
LT000842RU_CTRL                                <NA> 2_Ever_>100
LT001600RL_ILD                                1.903 2_Ever_>100
LT001796RU_CTRL                                <NA> 2_Ever_>100
LT002410RM_ILD                                 0.03 2_Ever_>100
                predicted_fcv_pre_bd predicted_fev1_pre_bd
LT000216LL_ILD                  <NA>                    56
LT000379LU_ILD                  <NA>                    67
LT000842RU_CTRL                 <NA>                    96
LT001600RL_ILD                  <NA>                    40
LT001796RU_CTRL                 <NA>                   107
LT002410RM_ILD                  <NA>                    56
                predicted_fev1_post_bd predicted_fcv_post_bd predicted_dlco
LT000216LL_ILD                    <NA>                  <NA>             36
LT000379LU_ILD                    <NA>                  <NA>             42
LT000842RU_CTRL                   <NA>                  <NA>             78
LT001600RL_ILD                    <NA>                  <NA>             16
LT001796RU_CTRL                    110                  <NA>            107
LT002410RM_ILD                      60                  <NA>             63
```

Now while I'm fairly happy with this result, it took me some time to cook, and it is quite inflexible (extremely tailored to this specific dataset) so I wanted to know the following:

1. is there a quick fix in Excel for this kind of situation?
2. alternatively, or actually even better: is there a base/tidyverse
   way to deal with this in R in a way that is not as asinine as the
       one I have come up with?

thanks in advance!

Comment: For an Excel solution, I'd start with setting up a data connection to the table, so you can import the data to Excel, rather than copy/paste.  Depending on the results, I would then use either Power Query or VBA to rearrange the data as required.  Can you share the URL?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @RonRosenfeld. This is where the table comes from: [link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/geo2r/?acc=GSE47460&platform=GPL14550) (see "Samples" frame).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the large cells in your original data are merged cells,
this is quite straightforward with the help of **openxlsx** and **tidyr**. Regardless, I would second @RonRosenfeld's suggestion (in the comments) of setting up a data connection to your remote source rather than copy-pasting.

I created (see code at end of post) a simplified example file, messy.xlsx, to demonstrate one option for the data wrangling process:

[image: Messy Excel data.]

You can first read the Excel file with `read.xlsx()`, preserving the
structure implied by the merged cells, and then `separate()` and `spread()`
the different characteristics into columns of their own:

```r
library(openxlsx)
library(tidyr)

# Repeat merged cell value accross all cells
messy <- read.xlsx("messy.xlsx", fillMergedCells = TRUE)

# Create a column for each characteristic
messy %>%
  separate(
    characteristics,
    into = c("variable", "value"),
    sep = ": "
  ) %>% 
  spread(variable, value)
#>   subject a b    c
#> 1     101 1 2    3
#> 2     102 2 8 <NA>
```

**Sample data:**

```r
library(openxlsx)

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet 1")

df <- data.frame(
  subject = c(101, NA, NA, 102, NA),
  characteristics = c("a: 1", "b: 2", "c: 3", "a: 2", "b: 8")
)

writeData(wb, 1, df)

mergeCells(wb, 1, 1, 2:4)
mergeCells(wb, 1, 1, 5:6)

saveWorkbook(wb, "messy.xlsx")
```

Created on 2018-07-17 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).

Comment: Thanks @MikkoMarttila. This works really well and is easy to implement. I think this is the time I get my stuff together and start learning tidyverse for real. Thanks a lot. Would upvote but I don't have enough street credibility.